# Unbiased Estimator of Days Until Completion?

Tags: estimation, bias

I'm trying to get an estimate of average number of days until some event occurs (the event is **guaranteed** to eventually occur). I have some sample where this event has already occured for most observations, so the number of days is known. However, this event has yet to occur for many other observations. I can't just omit those observations, since this will bias the average downwards. Can I get an unbiased estimate of the average? If so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: Maximum likelihood may be possible. However, ML estimators are not unbiased in general. You have some data that is called right-censored. Do you know anything about the distributional form of your time-to-event data? If so, you can use that. If not, you will need to use a nonparametric fit such as Kaplan-Meier.

Comment: I'm not sure about the true distributional form of my data. Just a shot in the dark, I would assume it's perhaps log-normal. Anyway, I think it would be better to try your alternative suggestion, a nonparametric fit. Although, I'm not familiar with any such methods. I'll look into Kaplan-Meier. Thanks!